# Getting JPA to generate tables with specified row format

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.3

I am using play 2 framework with JPA hibernate. My goal is to get JPA to generate tables on a fresh database using specific ROW_FORMAT:

This is what JPA executes on start:

```
create table Admin (
  ..
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And this is what I want:

```
create table Admin (
  ..
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

The persistance.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I tried looking for ways to use annotations in the java code, or a specific property in for the XML conf. I had no luck.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by subclassing MySQL5InnoDBDialect and overriding the `getTableTypeString()` method as below.

```
public class MySQL5CustomInnoDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect{

    /**
     * Call to super returns " type=innodb". 'Type' is a 
     * deprecated MySQL synonym for 'engine'         
     * so you may want to ignore the super call and use:
     * " engine=innodb ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC"       
     */
    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return super.getTableTypeString() + " ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC";
    }   
}
```

And obviously set this as your dialect:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.foo.MySQL5CustomInnoDBDialect"/>
```